# Is there a common name for the shape described as a segment of a circle or ellipse?

Tags: geometry, terminology

A circular segment is a region of the area inside a circle partitioned from the rest of the circular area by a chord. Is there a common name for this shape, other than "circular segment"?

If so, is there also a common name for the ellipse analogy of a circular segment?

Comment: @Joshua Wang Isn't an arc just a connected part of a curve? As in, it's not a name for the shape, but rather the curve bounding the shape (minus the chord).

Comment: elliptical segment

Comment: @achillehui Alright, I give. I was hoping for something more colloquial, but it doesn't seem such a thing exists. If you make this an answer I'll UV and accept.